# Creating a loop in R to generate list of correlations of neuralnet model

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to create a loop that completes 10 iterations (nrl from 1 to 10), for each iteration the value of nrl is the hidden node value. The correlation between the models prediction of the test set vs actual test set values should be  stored into a list for each iteration. This is what I have so far:

```
 nrl = 1
    while(nrl < 11)
{
  set.seed(123)
  neural_model1 <- neuralnet( formula = C ~ A + B 
                          ,  data = data_train,hidden = nrl)

  model_results <- compute(neural_model1,data_test)
  predicted <- n_model_results$net.result
  cor(predicted,data_test$C)
 nrl = nrl+1
}
```

How would I create the list of correlations?

Comment: How do you figure `hidden = nrl` doesn't work? You can create a new list `saved.cor <- vector("list", 10)` and save the result using `saved.cor[nrl] <- cor(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. As for "hidden = nrl" not working, I was mistaken.